# Is $G=\{ e\}$ both torsion group and a torsion-free group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, torsion-groups

Is $G=\{ e\}$ a torsion group or a torsion-free group?

Because all elements in $G$ has finite order, it is a torsion group.

Because $e$ is the only element in $G$ with finite order, it is a torsion-free group.

Therefore, $G=\{ e\}$ is both torsion group and torsion-free group.

Comment: It is definitely torsion. I would say it is torsion-free so the definition satisfies the rule: "Every subgroup of a torsion-free group is torsion-free." But I can see defining it otherwise.

Comment: The trivial group is the free group on the empty-set, so it is not just torsion-free it is free!

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you!